# Deploying on ubuntu, running java, with log4j2, class names don't show up

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a jersey app using jdk 1.7 on ubuntu. The log4j2.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF">
    <appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/var/log/oneid/oneid.log"
                     filePattern="/var/log/oneid/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
            </Policies>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <Async name="Async">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Async>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="Async" />
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

On ubuntu:

```
2014-04-11 03:24:26,295 DEBUG ? [qtp510734793-482 - /id/1.0/session/start?appKey=e5c5f919c068447d1c49] thread qtp510734793-482 - /id/1.0/session/start?
```

On my mac:

```
2014-04-10 20:21:08,183 DEBUG c.c.p.r.UpdateNeighborResource [qtp875070127-192 - /id/1.0/uns/testEvent?appKey=72df66fcd61449588b98bc57ef7043e4] testEvent: id: 6442450986 message # 18
```

Class and package shows up fine running locally, but when I deploy to ubuntu, I get a ? mark where the package/class should be. Any ideas?

Comment: %c does resolve my issue, if you'd like to post an answer, I'll give you credit.

Comment: Ah, thanks, but I really didn't do anything. Give credit to those in the linked question/answer. If you have your answer, consider closing the question.